# How to correct the inclination of an old chair

Tags: carpentry, bolts

I have an old easy chair, which I'm thinking to polish and use it.
The chair is made of teakwood and has nut and bolts at the joints. As it is decades old and was unused for a long time, the holes at the joints where the nuts and bolts are mated have become big making the chair to angle towards left. This nut and bolts are rusted and cannot be removed either.
 Should I replace the bolts with bigger bolts?
 How can I repair this and correct the inclination.

Comment: Some photos might be helpful.

Comment: Definitely photos. If the problem is that the bolts can't be tightened enough to make the chair rigid, I'd be inclined to suggest gluing in hardwood plugs and re-drilling the holes... but there may be other alternatives involving simply gluing those joints rather than counting on the bolts, or installing some shims between the pieces so the bolts apply force in more useful directions. Hardware can always be removed, it's just a question of how hard you have to work to do so...